# Spring Boot not Autowiring on integration tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm currently working on a project using Spring Framework and Spring Boot. I've spent a couple of hours trying to run an integration test for saving data to the database, but every time I try it fails. It seems Autowiring is not working for one of the dependencies I need. I'm trying to save a client to my database, and I need to store certain information about where to store a certificate/key pair. That info is obtained from another table that stores the current storage politics. I load it in prepareClient (that method does other things, but are irrelevant. Please ignore generateNss, generateName and generateLastName too, just dummy methods to get fake information).

Here's my integration test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@Slf4j
public class ClientTest {
    @Autowired
    private ClientOperations clientRepo;
    @Autowired
    private StorageConfiguration storageConfiguration;

    @Test
    public void saveClient() {
        int[] numbers = getNumbers();
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
            String name = "";
            String lastName = "";
            name = generateName();
            lastName = generateLastName();
            String nss = generateNss();
            Client client = new Client();
            client.setNss(nss);
            client.setName(name);
            client.setLastName(lastName);
            client = prepareClient(client);
            ResponseData rd = clientRepo.saveClient(((long) numbers[i]), client);
            rd.print();
        }
    }

private Client prepareClient(Client client) {
 //More stuff goes in here...

        boolean isCertificateCloudStored = storageConfiguration.isCertificateCloudStored();
        boolean isKeyCloudStored = storageConfiguration.isKeyCloudStored();
        client.isCertificateCloudStored(isCertificateCloudStored);
        client.isKeyCloudStored(!isKeyCloudStored);
        return client;
    }
```

My main function:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class ClientsMicroserviceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClientsMicroserviceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.sat.com.sat.downloaderservice.StorageConfiguration.isCertificateCloudStored()" because "this.storageConfiguration" is null
```

However, this is only happening when trying to test. I've run the application an performed a couple of succesful inserts via HTTP Post on a Controller with Postman. Those request use the same logic I'm testing, including reading storageConfiguration, so it's not an issue on the implementation of the class. And bad luck, I've got a huge bunch of rules to test and there's no way I can do that if I don't do most of them with code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sat.downloaderservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>clients-creation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sat-clientes</name>
    <description>Microservice that handles client creation</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.33.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev171-1.25.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!--<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>-->
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I've been struggling with this for a bit but I ran out of ideas. Thanks for your time!

Comment: It happens when spring context is not loaded. You should add annotation `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` to `ClientTest` class.

Comment: An `@Autowired` field cannot be `null` Spring would barf about that and not your test. Which means you aren't running your test with Spring. I suspect your `@Test` is from JUnit4, whilst using Junit5 to run your test. If you are running with junit4 you need to add `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` or fix your `@Test` annotation to be the JUnit5 one. Unrelated **pro-tip**, remove the `jackson-databind`, `validation-api` and `junit-jupiter-api` depndencies. They are already part of the included starters (and will lead to issues when upgrading).